# Promise To Upload File - how to add all files in directory

Tags: robotframework

Currently I have to give single file name to upload the file.
How do I let robot to keep selecting the files in `'Files'` directory then click upload?

```
*** Settings ***
Library    Browser
Library    OTP
Library    BuiltIn
Library    OperatingSystem

*** Test Cases ***
    Upload Files
        ${promise}=    Promise To Upload File    ${CURDIR}/Files/doc1.txt
        Click          ${Button-Upload}
        ${upload_result}=  Wait For  ${promise}
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do it , however the result can be fine tuned.
this solution did click upload - select file - click upload - select file.
finding solution to click upload - select multiple files (manual way: use keyboard ctrl + click to select more files).

```
*** Settings ***
Library    Browser
Library    OperatingSystem
Resource   ../Resources/BrowserParameters.robot
Resource   ../Resources/BrowserResources.robot

#Select Browser: chromium or firefox
Test Setup      Test Setup    Browser=chromium
Test Teardown   Test Teardown

*** Test Cases ***
001-01-Upload-20-Videos
    Click     ${Page-Inference}
    @{my_file_list}=    OperatingSystem.List Files In Directory    ${path_to_directory}
    FOR    ${file}    IN    @{my_file_list}
    ${result}=    Upload Video       ${path_to_directory}${/}${file}
    END
```